# Scope Search For Smartsheet API

Tags: smartsheet-api

Does anyone know of a way to limit the a search to a specific column only?  The documentation is showing query by fuzzy or exact match, but the data I am searching for is numerical and may show up in other columns, for rows that I am not trying to retrieve.  The idea here is to search for a specific value in a column and return the row ID associated.  I have all of that, but I keep getting multiple results due to no column scoping.

Using something simple like below, but the search is over the entire sheet.

```
IRM "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/search?query=12345" -Headers......
```

Answer (score 0):

The Smartsheet API does not currently support searching a specific column of a sheet like you've described. Instead of using the [Search Sheet](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/search#operation/list-search-sheet) operation to achieve your objective (identify rows with a specified value in a given cell so that you can obtain data from another cell in those rows), you might consider one of the following approaches.

**Approach #1**:

- Start by issuing a [Search Sheet](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/search#operation/list-search-sheet) request to identify anywhere that the specified term appears in the sheet.
- Iterate through the results in the response, and for each item in the results where `objectType` = `row`, issue a [Get Row](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/rows#operation/row-get) request to retrieve that row.
- For each row that you retrieve, evaluate the value of the cell that you're interested in. If the cell contains the specified value, obtain the values from the other cell(s) in that row that you want.

**Approach #2**:

- Issue a [Get Sheet](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/sheets#operation/getSheet) request to retrieve all data from the sheet. (See [Paging Query String Parameters](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#section/Work-at-Scale/Paging) for info about how to request that *all* rows be returned in a single response.)
- Iterate through the rows in the response, and for each row, evaluate the value of the cell that you're interested in. If the cell contains the specified value, obtain the values from the other cell(s) in that row that you want.

To use either approach you'll need to know the `ID` of the column(s) that you're wanting to access programmatically. You can get column IDs by issuing a [List Columns](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/columns#operation/columns-listOnSheet) request, if you don't already know them.

Either of these approaches should let you achieve your objective. Which approach ends up being more efficient will depend upon at least a couple of factors: how many matches are most likely to be found for the data you're searching for in the column you're evaluating, and how many rows your sheet contains.

- **Approach #1** will require issuing one request to get search results, and then an additional request for each row in the sheet where the specified data is found. If you're likely to only find a handful of matches throughout the sheet, then this approach would be a reasonable choice. On the other hand, if you're likely to find lots of matches throughout the sheet, then this approach would mean issuing lots of API requests (to retrieve each row where a match was found), which could be time consuming.
- **Approach #2** *could* require issuing only one API request (to get all data in the sheet), but then you'll need to iterate through all the rows in the sheet to evaluate cell values for every row. If you use this approach, be mindful that by default only **100** rows are returned per **Get Sheet** request. See [Paging Query String Parameters](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#section/Work-at-Scale/Paging) in the docs for info about how you can request more than 100 rows at once.